# Symfony2 dependecy injection doesn't work with controller

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

According to [Symfony2 Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/securing_services.html) I'm trying to secure controller via dependecy injection, but I'm getting error `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\ExampleBundle\Controller\DefaultController::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface, none given, called in /var/www/example/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 4706 and defined in /var/www/example/src/Acme/ExampleBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 13`

Here is my services.yml

```
parameters:
    acme_example.default.class: Acme\ExampleBundle\Controller\DefaultController

services:
    acme_example.default:
        class: %acme_example.default.class%
        arguments: [@security.context]
```

and controller:

```php
namespace Acme\ExampleBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext)
    {
        if(false === $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'))
        {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }                
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new Response('OK');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure your controllers as services you need to use a slightly different syntax when referencing them in your routes. Instead of `AcmeExampleBundle:Default:index` you should use `acme_example.default:indexAction`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;` in your controller. Without it, the `SecurityContextInterface` type hint in the constructor won't resolve.

Also, make sure your controller is actually being called as a service. The error you posted is complaining that *nothing* was sent to the constructor, which sounds to me like you're using your controller the 'default' way. See [this cookbook page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) on how to setup a controller as a service.

Answer (score 0):

The class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller extends ContainerAware base class. This class ha whole the container accessible via $container local property, so you should not inject any services to a controller service, because you can access SecurityContext via `$this->container->get('security.context')`.